# Which alternatives to PFAS-contaminated cardboards for vermicomposting?

Tags: waste, pollution, vermicomposting, pfas

Vermicomposters add cardboard pieces to their waste in order to provide a source of carbon and to dry/ventilate the medium to avoid any hot fermentation. The amount of cardboard is usually high to balance the high content of water in vegetable waste.

However, cardboards are usually recycled from old cardboard which the recycling process tolerates a certain amount of plastic (rubber etc) and other pollutants. Some of these pollutants are [PFAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-_and_polyfluoroalkyl_substances), which are "eternal" pollutants as they are incredibly stable, then they accumulate every each recycling process. They are [known](https://echa.europa.eu/hot-topics/perfluoroalkyl-chemicals-pfas) to be used in cardboard or paper food-packaging as water and grease repellents.

Then the compost from vermicomposting could include a large amount of PFAS. What would be a good alternative to cardboard for vermicomposting in a city flat (i.e. no access to dead leaves etc)?

Comment: Good question. More on PFAS in "compostable" paper-based food packaging: https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2023/apr/17/pfas-forever-chemicals-food-containers-study, but no short-term solution unfortunately.